# Building multi-release jar for a project involving dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-9, multi-release-jar

I am trying to build multi-release jar for a maven project involving external dependencies. The reason why I emphasize on "external dependencies" is because I succeeded in building multi-release jar following the instructions here: http://in.relation.to/2017/02/13/building-multi-release-jars-with-maven/ for a project which no external dependencies in the pom. When I altered this project to have a dependency in the pom, I got error saying: package does not exist. The reported package exists in the dependency included. This is the project structure:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKbt9.png)

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.hibernate.demos</groupId>
<artifactId>multi-release-jar-demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>multi-release-jar-demo</name>
<url>http://hibernate.org/</url>

<properties>
    <commonslang.version>3.8.1</commonslang.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java9.sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java9</java9.sourceDirectory>
    <java9.build.outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes-java9</java9.build.outputDirectory>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-java9</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <mkdir dir="${java9.build.outputDirectory}" />
                            <javac srcdir="${java9.sourceDirectory}" destdir="${java9.build.outputDirectory}"
                                classpath="${project.build.outputDirectory}" includeantruntime="false" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/versions/9</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${java9.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                        <!--<Main-Class>org.hibernate.demos.mrjar.Main</Main-Class>-->
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!--<finalName>mr-jar-demo</finalName>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>initialize</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

src/main/java9/org/hibernate/demos/mrjar/ProcessIdProvider.java:

```
public class ProcessIdProvider {
    public ProcessIdDescriptor getPid() {
        Configuration properties = null;
        long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
        return new ProcessIdDescriptor( pid, "ProcessHandle" );
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Documents/Development/hibernate-demos/java9/multi-release-jar-demo/src/main/java9/org/hibernate/demos/mrjar/ProcessIdProvider.java:7: error: package org.apache.commons.configuration does not exist
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;
                                       ^
/Documents/Development/hibernate-demos/java9/multi-release-jar-demo/src/main/java9/org/hibernate/demos/mrjar/ProcessIdProvider.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Configuration properties = null;
        ^
  symbol:   class Configuration
  location: class ProcessIdProvider
```

To note, this error appears only for the class residing inside the folder src/main/java9 and the file inside src/main/java compiles successfully. I don't seem to find any sample maven project with dependencies building a multi-release jar.

Comment: Can you list the error completely and the project structure with your pom.xml in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the same approach used by [SL4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), I use the same configuration from their [pom.xml](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/715b5911858b13a89e5fa9df13f4ca03d72850f7/pom.xml#L162-L222), in my case for java 11 and 12.

The properties:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
  <java12-outputdirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/versions/12</java12-outputdirectory>
  <java12-build-directory>${project.build.directory}/classes-java12</java12-build-directory>
  <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.3.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

The build section:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-compile</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <source>12</source>
            <target>12</target>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>module-compile</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <release>12</release>
            <compileSourceRoots>
              <compileSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/java12</compileSourceRoot>
            </compileSourceRoots>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/versions/12
            </outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
            <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The folder structure:
[image: Folder structure example]

The full example is [here](https://github.com/earth001/java-11-upgrade-certification-practice).

Comment: Note that, since version 3.8.0 of the maven-compiler-plugin supports a multiReleaseOutput option which can compile classes directly to the appropriate META-INF/versions/{release} directory.

So, instead of:

<outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/versions/9</outputDirectory>

We can write:

<multiReleaseOutput>true</multiReleaseOutput>